# API to surface emails created in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Is there a SF REST API to surface emails created in Marketing Cloud?

For instance, I'm attempting to create an archive of past emails on a website. Instead of manually inputting the data, I would like to get access to a list of emails.

Comment: its not clear what you are looking for, is this for a subscriber, or just all emails in an account?

Comment: Just all emails in an account

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/content-api.html#overview

Comment: Do keep in mind, that most emails contain certain degree of personalisation. Hence you need to consider the fact, that there might not me such thing as simply fetching and presenting the “raw” email on your website

Answer (score 1):

Simply extending [@EazyE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/66853/eazye)'s suggestion from the comments, you can use REST API's endpoint - GET `/asset/v1/content/assets/` to get all assets in your Content Builder.

However, since you want to get only emails, you would need to add an advanced query on top, e.g. filter by `assetType.id` where it equals `207`, `208`, and `209`. Here is the [list of all asset types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/base-asset-types.html#asset-types) and you can find related IDs there as well. Also, your endpoint and request method would change.

Thus you need to:

1. Authorise yourself (there are plenty of resources explaining how to do that with correct scopes and where to get credentials)
2. Create POST request to this endpoint -`https://[your_domain].rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/query`
3. Add `Content-Type` = `application/json` in Headers
4. Add raw JSON Body, which would filter the request to result only in Asset Types that have ID from `207` to `209` inclusively -

```
{
    "query": {
        "leftOperand": {
            "property": "assetType.id",
            "simpleOperator": "lessThanOrEqual",
            "value": 209
        },
        "logicalOperator": "AND",
        "rightOperand": {
            "property": "assetType.id",
            "simpleOperator": "greaterThanOrEqual",
            "value": 207
        }
    }
}
```

5. Send the request.

Resources:

- [Content Builder REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/content-api.html#overview)
- [Advanced Query on Assets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetAdvancedQuery.htm)
- [List of Asset Types in Content Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/base-asset-types.html#asset-types)